# Concatinating files with Timestamp in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

How can I concatenate a time stamp with the output generated by pig. I need to save the output generated by pig to one more folder with a time stamp so that it can be used as historical data for a future purpose. I tried to use CurrentTime() but it gave me a error like this:

```
2015-03-31 19:29:58,249 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1200: <file script.pig, line 1> Cannot expand macro 'CurrentTime'. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion.
```

How do I define this macro?

Here is the code :

```
A = load '/user/root/b2.out';
X = FILTER A BY ($2 == 'Error') OR ($2=='Info') OR ($2=='Warning') OR ($2=='Critical');
D = FOREACH X GENERATE $0,$2,$4,$6,$8;
store D into CONCAT('/user/root/ELABD/finalout',CurrentTime());
```

Comment: Could you show what code you have right now?

Comment: @mr2ert updated the code in the question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCAT` can only be used inside a relation (aka `foreach` statement), so you cannot use it to construct an output file location.

Two possible solutions here I think:

Use a `%declare` statement in your pig script that uses something like `date` in bash to get current time and use that as parameter, e.g.

```
%declare DATETIME `date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S`
...
store D into '/user/root/ELABD/finalout/$DATETIME';
```

Alternatively use something like [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) to schedule your pig jobs and have Oozie generate your output location based on date/time.

Comment: I am facing a weird error on something similar. If I do a declare with your statement, Pig 0.12 (being run via Hue on Amazon EMR) gives an error:
               
    ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext  - Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 12.
Was expecting one of:
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <OTHER> ...
    <LITERAL> ...
    <SHELLCMD> ...

Comment: Have you tried adding a ';' at the end of the declare statement?